# Why does PyQt5 use both "cls" and "self"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pyqt, pyqt5

When subclassing `QtCore.QAbstractTableModel`, my editor suggested overriding this symbol.

```
def data(cls, self, QModelIndex, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        return super().data(self, QModelIndex, role=role)
```

The `data()` method will never be a class method, it is always an instance method. I know about the convention to use `cls` *instead* of `self` when the method is annotated with `@classmethod`, but I'm confused as to why the signatures from PyQt5 use both. As far as I know, Python will only populate the first, and then `cls` will be what I would expect `self` to be. Then `self` would be a normal argument at that point.

What am I misunderstanding? What should my symbols be when overriding the methods?

Comment: Looks like your editor is buggy, then, doesn't it?

Comment: @ekhumoro Well I wasn't sure, since so many people use VS Code for Python I would have expected it not to be.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the bug is in whatever tool generates those method stubs for the pyqt bindings. Presumably the editor doesn't have them by default - you have to install them separately, right? Or is there some kind of third-party pyqt extension?

Comment: Are we talking about [PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.data](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.data)? If that's the case then the others are right and your editor is drunk.

Comment: @cglacet Yes, but PySide is dead and PyQt5 should be its replacement.